# EJB Timer every two years

Tags: timer, ejb, wildfly

I have a number range defined in my database to retrieve order numbers. Every two years, the numbers should be reset to start again with 1.

So I created the following Quartz Cron expression '0 0 0 1 1 ? */2' using cron-utils (https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils) to do the reset every two years on Jan, 1st.
This will be parsed correctly.

The problem now is, that I'm not able to create an EJB TimerService with that expression, because

1. the '?' character is not supported and
2. year doesn't support values of types INCREMENT.

So how to achieve this?

I am running my application on WildFly 23 using JDK11.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not at all convinced of this design, if you expect that your code will last 10 years, how about something like:

```
0 0 0 1 1 ? 2023,2025,2027,2029,2031,2033
```

That would let you retire with your code working 10 more years.  If you need it to run longer then add a few more years.  The `?` is supported according to the [Quartz docs](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html).

Comment: You are right, the `?` is supported according to the Quartz docs, but EJB `TimerService#createCalendarTimer` throws an `IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEJB0293: Could not parse: ? in schedule expression`.

Comment: You said Quartz.  Are you using the standard `@Schedule` EJB instead?

Comment: As mentioned above, I am using `TimerService#createCalendarTimer` because the configuration for the timer is read from a database and therefore i can not use `@Schedule` annotation